# How cloudflare SSL works

Tags: ssl, encryption

I have a doubt that I had for years and now I decided to try to understand it. I know that when a user hits a website with SSL all headers are encrypted, even the HOST header.

So, in order to enable SSL in a server, you need to have a single IP to every certificate you have cause Apache, for example, wont know which VHOST it should redirect the user if the HOST header is encrypted.

My question is: how does Cloudflare knows which domain the user is using to access its CDN if it does not know the HOST before the decrypt happens?

Comment: one-ip-per-ssl is oldschool. nowadays it's not necessary anymore, as the requested hostname is part of the ssl link negotation. that and cloudflare uses wildcard certificates (to some level) so that pretty much any hostname would validate as legit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) (SNI) allows TLS clients to specify the host they are attempting to connect to give the server a chance to serve the right certificate. It is supported in **most**  browsers.

[CloudFlare's page on their free SSL offering](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/) indicates they use SNI.

---

Now, CloudFlare has multiple offerings. Their paid plans don't actually rely on SNI (that's why they [support all browsers](https://www.cloudflare.com/plans/)). Only the free plans do.

For the paid plans, CloudFlare presumably uses dedicated IPs, though even in that case they can still pool multiple domains under a single certificate (using [Subject Alternative Names](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.6)).

Comment: @Thomas Orozco I have bought an SSL from some certificate authority and I would like to use it with my CloudFlare account (Free) instead of using the free SSL provided by CloudFlare. Is it possible to set it up in a way that I have my site working with my custom SSL & CloudFlare ? or the only option I have is to upgrade my account to Business/Entreprise? Thanks for your help!